# How To Optimize A Branch-And-Bound Optimization With Constraints

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, branch-and-bound

I'm working on a program to find a subset of items that maximizes the total value of those items while meeting several constraints on various properties of those items. I've implemented a recursive branch-and-bound algorithm that works on inputs of small sizes (input array of size ~15, subset of size ~6 or so), but if the input array size is >20 or so then the algorithm never finishes running. The target dataset I have is ~1000 items, so would need to greatly improve the efficiency.

In more detail, I have an input list of objects of this structure:

```
class Player {
 public:
  POSITION position;
  std::unordered_map<CATEGORY, float> category_zscores;
  std::string name;
  int cost;
  float total_zscore;

  Player(const std::string& name,
         const std::unordered_map<CATEGORY, float>& category_zscores,
         POSITION position, const std::vector<POSITION>& positions, int cost)
      : name(name),
        category_zscores(category_zscores),
        position(position),
        positions(positions),
        cost(cost) {
    total_zscore = getTotalPlayerZScore();
  }

 private:
  float getTotalPlayerZScore() const {
    float total_zscore = 0.0;
    for (const auto& category : category_zscores) {
      total_zscore += category.second;
    }
    return total_zscore;
  }
};
```

And have implemented the following branch-and-bound algorithm:

```
void findBestTeam(const std::vector<Player>& players, std::vector<Player>& current_team, std::vector<Player>& best_team, int index) {
    
    // First verify that current_team passes constraints on total cost, team size, minimum positions and minimum zscore sums
    if (!checkConstraints(current_team)) {
        return;
    }

    // If current_team has met all constraints and is full roster size, then check if it's a new best team
    if (current_team.size() == TEAM_SIZE_LIMIT && getTotalTeamZScore(current_team) > getTotalTeamZScore(best_team)) {
        std::vector<Player> temp; 
        for (const auto& player : current_team) {
            temp.push_back(player);
        }
        best_team = temp;
        return;
    }

    // If reached end of players array then return
    if (index == players.size()) {
        return;
    }


    // Recursive call without including the current player
    findBestTeam(players, current_team, best_team, index + 1);

    // Recursive call including the current player
    current_team.push_back(players.at(index));
    findBestTeam(players, current_team, best_team, index + 1);
    current_team.pop_back();
}
```

The constraints are somewhat complicated:

```
bool checkConstraints(std::vector<Player> team) {
    if (team.empty()) {
        return true;
    }
    if (team.size() > TEAM_SIZE_LIMIT) {
        return false;
    }
    int cost = getTotalTeamCost(team);
    int numOpenSpots = TEAM_SIZE_LIMIT - team.size();

    // this check is strictly for pruning, to try and figure out early on if cost constraint cannot be met in this branch
    if (cost > TEAM_COST_LIMIT || (TEAM_COST_LIMIT - cost) < numOpenSpots) {
        return false;
    }
    int guardsNeeded = MIN_PLAYERS_PER_POSITION.at(POSITION::guard) - std::count_if(team.begin(), team.end(), [](const Player& player) {
        return player.position == POSITION::guard;
    });
    int forwardNeeded = MIN_PLAYERS_PER_POSITION.at(POSITION::forward) - std::count_if(team.begin(), team.end(), [](const Player& player) {
        return player.position == POSITION::forward;
    });
    int centersNeeded = MIN_PLAYERS_PER_POSITION.at(POSITION::center) - std::count_if(team.begin(), team.end(), [](const Player& player) {
        return player.position == POSITION::center;
    });

    // this check is strictly for pruning, to try and figure out early on if position constraints cannot be met in this branch
    if (guardsNeeded > numOpenSpots || forwardNeeded > numOpenSpots || centersNeeded > numOpenSpots) {
        return false;
    }

    // this check is for position constraint, to ensure a full roster has met the minimum requirements at each position
    if (team.size() == TEAM_SIZE_LIMIT) {
        for (CATEGORY category : { /*fg,*/ ft, threes, points, /*rebounds,*/ assists, steals, blocks, /*tos*/ }) {
            if (getTotalTeamZScoreForCategory(team, category) < MIN_ZSCORE_PER_CAT) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

How would I go about improving the efficiency of this algorithm? I've thought a bit about dynamic programming in this case, but I'm unsure if there are enough overlapping subproblems given the constraints that must be applied. Will branch-and-bound approach ever work for a problem like this? What class of algorithm could solve this efficiently?

Appreciate any advice, has been years since I've taken algorithm courses and this side project is my first foray into something like this :)

Comment: Home-grown B&B codes (even specialized ones) are typically no match for what you can find in existing MIP solvers. Of course, that requires you to formulate your problem as a MIP.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen how would i go about formulating this an an MIP? that's not something I've learned about before.. how does that work, I use some existing MIP solver rather than writing an algorithm to do this myself? Do you have any helpful starting resources?

Comment: Learning about branch&bound algorithms without being told about mixed-integer programming, is like learning about databases without mentioning SQL. You should ask your money back.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen uh, i disagree, a normal college introductory data structures & algorithms course will have branch&bound as part of the fundamental curriculum and will definitely not teach about mixed-integer programming. MIP definitely falls more under the scope of upper-level algorithms courses. But thanks I guess for mentioning something vague to look into with no followup resources.